# How to fix [Error: Network Error] calling localhost api using react native and express js

Tags: react-native, express

I'am currently studying **React native** and **Express JS** for my server side. So now I do practicing calling api from express js to react native and I use **axios** to call http request. My problem is in my cmd it shows that [Error: Network Error]. To be more specific I will show you guys my sample work both server.js and components and sample screenshot Error on my cmd.

> [Error: Network Error]

Server JS:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '192.168.61.1',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'sample_db'
});

if(connection) {
    console.log(connection);
}


// Starting our app.
const app = express();

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

// Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'mobile' table.

app.get('/api/readings', function (req, res) {

    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'mobile' table).

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_mobile', function (error, results, fields) {

      // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
      if (error) throw error;

      // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// get the specific meter

app.get('/api/readings/:id', function (req, res) {

    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'mobile' table).

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_mobile WHERE id = ?',req.params.id, function (error, results, fields) {

      // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
      if (error) throw error;

      // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});



// Starting our server.
app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('http://192.168.61.1/api/readings');
});
```

Axios:

```
axios.get('http://192.168.61.1:3000/api/readings')
    .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // always executed
    });
```

Response:

[image: Response]

Comment: if you are running in android, you'll need to config clearText http traffic

Comment: The IP address 192.168.61.1 seems to be a gateway IP address please check if you are using correct IP address of your machine.